# Fontsetup (NewComputerModern) overwriting mathtools options

Tags: fontsetup

I do not know why mathtools does not use the intlimits options, which `amsmath` provides and which should be loadable for mathtools as written in the documentation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[default,upint]{fontsetup}
\usepackage[intlimits]{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \int_a^b f(x) \diff x
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The custom `diff` is just for an upright d.

It seems that `fontsetup` is the problem here. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem you've encountered doesn't appear to be a shortcoming of the `mathtools` package, as it also shows up if you replace `\usepackage[intlimits]{mathtools}` with `\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}`. Instead, it looks like using the `fontsetup` package somehow disables the `intlimits` option of `amsmath`.

Comment: @Mico Ok thanks. Do you have any idea how I can circumvent this and get the desired option to load?

Comment: You may want to contact the author of the `fontsetup` package and ask for a bug fix.

Comment: @Mico Alright. Thank you! I will update this question if I receive any answer.

Comment: As it has nothing to do with mathtools (other than it passes options on to amsmath) you might want to rephrase the question and perhaps remove the mathtools tag

Comment: It does not have to do with fontsetup or NewCM fonts. It is a problem of using together mathtools and unicode-math. fontsetup just requires unicode-math. Test without NewCM and without fontsetup but with mathtools+unicode-math

Comment: I can verify that this solution works fine with fontsetup, upint option and NewCM.